# Django not searching for translation messages

Tags: python, django, internationalization

Trying to figure out how Django i18n works. Already have read through the official and several other tutorials. The problem is that Django generates the .po file, but it doesn't contain messages from my models and Python scripts (well, I'm ready to live with the scripts, but models MUST be translated). Here are my settings:

```
LOCALE_PATHS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'install', 'locale'),
]


LANGUAGES = (
    ('ru', _('Russian')),
    ('en', _('English')),
)

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'
```

And here is the .po file ('locale' folder is located in the root of the project):

```
# SOME DESCRIPTIVE TITLE.
# Copyright (C) YEAR THE PACKAGE'S COPYRIGHT HOLDER
# This file is distributed under the same license as the PACKAGE package.
# FIRST AUTHOR <EMAIL@ADDRESS>, YEAR.
#
#, fuzzy
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: PACKAGE VERSION\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2017-05-12 12:26-0400\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: YEAR-MO-DA HO:MI+ZONE\n"
"Last-Translator: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\n"
"Language-Team: LANGUAGE <LL@li.org>\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=4; plural=(n%10==1 && n%100!=11 ? 0 : n%10>=2 && n%"
"10<=4 && (n%100<12 || n%100>14) ? 1 : n%10==0 || (n%10>=5 && n%10<=9) || (n%"
"100>=11 && n%100<=14)? 2 : 3);\n"

#: trackpost/settings.py:127
msgid "Russian"
msgstr ""

#: trackpost/settings.py:128
msgid "English"
msgstr ""
```

As you see, it contains only strings from settings. In models, I use `ugettext_lazy as _`.

Have been fighting with this for 3 days now. Any ideas why this is happening?

**UPD.** I translate some variables. One of them looks like `v = 'string'` and then `_(v)` and another is a text variable which I get through API. None of them is discovered by Django, although the first should be.

**UPD.** Here is the project structure (unimportant files like migrations missed):

```
├── account
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── binder.py
├── db.sqlite3
├── install
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── locale
│   │   └── ru
│   │       └── LC_MESSAGES
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── locale
│   └── ru
│       └── LC_MESSAGES
│           └── django.po
├── manage.py
├── nginx.conf
├── nohup.out
├── payments.py
├── trackpost
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── uwsgi.ini
```

Comment: could you please add a structure of your app? (include manage.py, settings and app folders)

Comment: @Taras added the structure. But how could that help?

Comment: @RyanSnow, and which translations are not discovered? The ones under the `install` app? Would you mind show your `settings`, please?

Comment: @nik_m yeah, the one under `install`. Don't understand you, my `settings` are already included (the imortant ones).

Comment: Do you have the install app included in INSTALLED_APPS setting list? That's why I asked to show your full settings.

Comment: @nik_m yeah, it's in the INSTALLED_APPS. Don't think it's worth including this in the question

Answer (score 1):

You should update the [`LOCALE_PATHS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-LOCALE_PATHS) list to include the `locale` directory of your app that holds the to-be-translated models.

```
LOCALE_PATHS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'myapp', 'locale'),  # translation lookup directory for "myapp" app
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'another_app', 'locale'),  # translation lookup directory for "another_app" app
]
```

Then, you should manually create the locale structure under your app, like this:

```
myapp/locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES/
```

Then, run `./manage.py makemessages --all` which will look under each `locale` dir declared inside the `LOCALE_PATHS` and create there the `.po` file. You know the rest (`./manage.py compilemessages`).

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't help. Maybe that's because I use variable in my app?

Comment: What variable? Edit your question and add the relevant code, please. I tested it locally and works like a charm.

Comment: oh, sorry, man, didn't see your comment. It's a text variable. In one place it looks like `v = 'string'` and then `_(v)`. In another place I try to translate a string variable which I get through API, and that could be a problem, but at least the first variable should be found by Django, and it isn't.

Comment: It should work. Did you updated your `LOCALE_PATHS` list? Update your question with what you tried.

Comment: I will add my structure in a moment. Actually, after updating LOCALE_PATHS and adding the locale folder for the app, nothing happens when I run `makemessages`. It doesn't create the .po file in the new folder

Comment: Also, please, verify that you run `./manage.py makemessages --all` instead of just `./manage.py makemessages`.